# AngularFire $add not resolving promises

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I have a simple bit of code adding an object to a $firebaseArray() like this:

```
var itemRef = database.ref('/somelist/of/items');
$scope.list = $firebaseArray(itemRef);
$scope.list.$add({name:"new item1"}).then(function(newItem) {
    console.log("I wish this log would show up");
}).catch(function(er) {
    console.log("This doesn't run either");
}).finally(function(res) {
    console.log("Added just to be sure, but also doesn't get here");
});
```

I've initialized firebase, and the $add() function works perfectly (as well as all of the other features, including Auth and Storage).

However, I need the key for the added item and the promise is never executed. My original attempt was based on the link below but I cannot even execute the simplified code above.

The original attempt:
https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebasearray-addnewdata

I tried to set up a plunker or jsfiddle to demo the error but, I feel like an idiot because I'm getting X-origin issues on both platforms.

Comment: Have you tried to add an error handler to your `.then` to see what errors occur?  also, that link isn't "the original attempt", it is a link to documentation.

Comment: Thanks Claies. I did that as well, but left it out of my posted example because the $add function is working.  but I've updated my question to include that bit.

Comment: P.S.  I may have misphrased it, but by "original attempt", I mean that the link is the source of my inspiration, it's what I'm trying to accomplish in my own code, using almost an exact copy of the code in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I spoke directly with the AngularFire folks and there is a bug with version 2.3.0 where it has compatibility issues with firebase 3.7.1.

For ref:
https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/issues/922